# ScrollView with ViewPager child not scrolling vertically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, motionevent

I have a `ScrollView` whose first child is a `ViewPager`.

I need to disable the vertical scroll of the `ViewPager` so that it only scrolls horizontally and let the vertical scroll be handled by the parent `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `ViewPager` has the behavior of scrolling `horizontally`. You need not to do anything else than setting an `Adapter` to it and put it inside `ScrollView`. All will work fine. 
If you are using some custom class or using another `ScrollView` inside the `ViewPager` Child, than show some code.